# Изменение позиций строк

Tags: powershell

Простенькая, казалось, задачка: поменять местами чётные и нечётные строки. Подумав, пришла к незатейливому алгоритму читать построчно файл, пихая строки во временный буфер, в котором после меняется порядок элементов. Иначе говоря:

```
$tmp = @()

try {
  $sr = [IO.StreamReader]::new((Convert-Path 'output.txt'))
  while ($sr.Peek() -gt 0) {
    $tmp += $sr.ReadLine()
    if ($tmp.Length -eq 2) {
      [Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse([String[]]$tmp)
      $tmp = @()
    }
  }
}
catch {
  Write-Host $_
}
finally {
  if ($sr) { $sr.Dispose() }
}
```

Всё ОК на файлах с чётным количеством строк, а вот при нечётном количестве выпадает последняя строка. Что за шаманство нужно произвести с буфером и можно ли вообще его не использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, насколько велик обрабатываемый файл. Если он небольшой можно поступить так:

`(gc output.txt | group {[math]::floor($script:i++ / 2)}).foreach{$_.group[1,0]} && rv i`

Прочитали файл целиком, сгруппировали строки попарно, поменяли каждую пару местами. Пусть вас не смущает в данном случае слово "пара", так как группировка элементов корректна даже при нечётном количестве строк.